# oozie error: Runtime error [E0604: Job does not exist [0000051-160824185250076-oozie-oozi-W@test_shell]

Tags: command-line-interface, oozie, hortonworks-data-platform

While running the oozie workflow from CLI, I am getting this error. I tried running the workflow from all the available node but still no luck. I tried running the same from Hue, it runs well.

Comment: Can you share couple of things.. logs from the launcher job (if any), workflow.xml and job.properties. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any logs on CLI. Below is my job.properties:
job.properties:
jobTracker=http://awdex01008.aws.merckcloud.com:8050
nameNode=hdfs://awdex01007.aws.merckcloud.com:8020
queueName=default
oozie.use.system.libpath=true
oozie.libpath=/user/oozie/share/lib/oozie
oozie.wf.application.path=hdfs://awdex01007:8020/user/x177861/ooziesqooptest
I am not able to paste workflow.xml here as its too long

Comment: You can always update the question with proper/more information. Thanks.

Comment: *"I don't see any logs on CLI"* -- does that mean that commands `oozie job -info 0000051-160824185250076-oozie-oozi-W` and `oozie job -log 0000051-160824185250076-oozie-oozi-W` return nothing?